# Make Ctrl+Arrow move though words in Windows Forms with C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms

In my Windows Forms project when I use the ctrl+arrow shortcut it jumps to either the end or beginning of the text instead of jumping between words. How can I fix that?

Comment: Where does this happen? In the code editor? In a Control that contains text, at run-time? If the former, did you edit the keyboard accelerators (`Edit.WordPrevious`, `Edit.WordNext`, for example. Maybe intended to modify the behavior of a specifc environment, set as `Global` instead).

Comment: It happens at run-time when I use it in a textbox, it works in the code editor, I did not edit the keyboard accelerators

Comment: Do you have code that handles KeyUp/KeyDown/KeyPress events? Otherwise, the TextBox and RichTextBox controls follow the standard pattern: `CTRL+LEFT/RIGHT` move the caret one word left/right, `CTRL+UP/DOWN` one paragraph up/down, `HOME/END` line start/line end, `CTRL+HOME/END` start/end of text. The words separator should be the ASCII Char 32.

Comment: I do have code that handles KeyDown, it clears the text from the textbox when you press Escape, can I keep it and still get the ctrl+arrows to work?

Comment: Why not? If it just handles `Keys.Escape`. Does it do anything else (that code or any other piece of code related to keyboard input)? Can you post the code related to this operation?

Comment: private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
                textBox2.Text = "";
                textBox3.Text = "";
                textBox4.Text = "";
                textBox5.Text = "";
                textBox6.Text = "";
                label4.Text = "";
                richTextBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }

Comment: (Don't post your code in comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58726698/edit) your question to update it ). This code doesn't compomise the normal behavior of `CTRL+LEFT/RIGHT`. Do you have the same result in any other application? Or other code that handles key presses in yours?

Comment: I seem to have made a mistake. It does move through words separated by space but I want it to move through words separated by dot as well. This one doesn't work, any Idea how to make it work?